# Link validation pattern for X (formerly Twitter)?

Tags: regex

I have this regex pattern that works well with twitter.com (or any other URL), but since it's now "X", when a link is copied and pasted it has the x.com in the copied link and then it will not work in my regex. What is the fix for this?

```js
const linkPattern = /^(http(s)?:\/\/)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)$|^x$/;
```

At the end of the pattern you will see the single char exception but it does not like it.

Comment: This was always a bad way to validate a URL, but specifically x isn't at least two characters.

Answer (score 0):

x.com is one letter so try recognising the length of one letter instead of >2
({1,256} instead of {2, 256})

const linkPattern = /^(http(s)?://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%.+~#=]{1,256}.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%+.~#?&//=]*)$|^x$/;

Comment: oooh thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a simpler and more specific pattern, also making use of the [RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) (adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3297265/5712053)):

```js
const linkRegExp = new RegExp('^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\\.)?x\\.com\/(\\w+)$', 'i')
```

Try [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) to validate it.

Generally, I consider RegEx not the ideal solution to validate URLs. Consider if you have an alternative.